# SonarQube security hotspot, Using regular expressions

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

I use the SonarQube for my Projects, and I have the Security Hotspot for **"^.*\+json[;]?\s*$"**:

```
       return mediaType != null 
             && (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(mediaType)
             || mediaType.getSubtype().matches("^.*\\+json[;]?\\s*$"));
   }
```

Hier is the Message from SonarQube for ,

Using regular expressions is security-sensitive. It has led in the past to the following vulnerabilities:

**[CVE-2017-16021](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-16021)**

**[CVE-2018-13863](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-13863)**

Evaluating regular expressions against input strings is potentially an extremely CPU-intensive task. Specially crafted regular expressions such as (a+)+s will take several seconds to evaluate the input string aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabs. The problem is that with every additional a character added to the input, the time required to evaluate the regex doubles. However, the equivalent regular expression, a+s (without grouping) is efficiently evaluated in milliseconds and scales linearly with the input size.

Evaluating such regular expressions opens the door to Regular expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) attacks. In the context of a web application, attackers can force the web server to spend all of its resources evaluating regular expressions thereby making the service inaccessible to genuine users.

This rule flags any execution of a hardcoded regular expression which has at least 3 characters and at least two instances of any of the following characters: *+{.

Example: (a+)*

Exceptions

Calls to String.split(regex) and String.split(regex, limit) will not raise an exception despite their use of a regular expression. These methods are used most of the time to split on simple regular expressions which don't create any vulnerabilities.

why?, and how can I it resolve?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry a little late but this will help:

[image: security hotspot]